# How to save an xml file as HTML file link using python?

Tags: python, html, xml

I need to save the xml file as HTML link using python code.

This is my python code:

```
 
src = r 'local/xml_formats/invoice.xml'
dest = r 'local/XML_files/new_invoice.xml'

new_path = shutil.copyfile(src, dest)
tree = ET.parse(new_path)
root = tree.getroot() 

#modifying code for the copied file 

tree.write(new_path)
```

As the code shows, now I save the xml file in local ( dest) but instead that I need to have it as HTML link.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is a "HTML link file / HTML file link"?

Comment: I mean a link where I will be accessed in browser to view the XML file.

Comment: This is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/75578898/407651. That one was closed because you failed to explain what you mean by "HTML link" or "HTML file link".